# icons won't show up in App Engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

need help I'm just a beginner, the icon inside the

```
<i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5">
```

wont show up when I run it using app Engine, but when I run it using XAMPP it shows up.

Here's the code of the app.yaml

```
application: project-for-school
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

#Directories

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /assets
  static_dir:  assets

- url: /js
  static_dir:  js

- url: /css/(.*\.(css|scss))$
  static_files: css/\1
  upload: css/.*\.(css|scss)$

- url: /scss/(.*\.(css|scss|svg|ttf|woff))$
  static_files: scss/\1
  upload: scss/.*\.(css|scss|svg|ttf|woff)$

- url: /pages
  static_dir:  pages

- url: .*/
  script: index.html

- url: /pages/login.html
  script: login.html
```

Inside the project folder I have the following:

```
- app.yaml
- favicon.ico
- index.html
- php.ini
- assets [folder]
- css [folder]
- img [folder]
- js [folder]
- pages [folder]
- scss [folder]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I generally don't like doing a person's homework, I think it would help you understand the url handling in app.yaml.  You are missing a handler for the directory `/img`  Try something like:

```
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
```